# how did this C program execute

Tags: c

i executed the code given below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    if(ch = printf(""))
        printf("It matters\n");
    else
        printf("It doesn't matters\n");
    return 0;
}
```

it gives output "It doesn't matters"
can someone please explain me how this code works. what happeps when ch = printf("") is executed>

Comment: Google "man printf" to learn what the return value from printf is.

Comment: Just FYI, if you're working on a *nix machine you can just type `man printf` at the terminal to get info about the function. You can replace `printf` with most of the standard functions. If you're working on Windoze google can give you the same results. Always good to do some homework into the pre/post conditions and I/O of the functions

Answer (score 9):

```
printf("")
```

returns the number of characters successfully printed. So the conidtion

```
if(ch = printf(""))
```

fails as `ch` is set to 0. Hence, the else clause is getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

from [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) manpage:

> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).

you're assigning the result of printf to ch, which returns the number of characters printed, as you print no characters, it returns 0, which is considered as false and then the else gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

Function `printf()` in C returns the length of the printed output. In your example, `printf("")` evaluates to `0`. This value is assigned to `ch` and is the value of the condition. `0` as an `if` condition means “false”: the else branch is taken.

Answer (score 0):

From `printf` documentation:

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

As you're writing an empty string, the `printf` returns 0. You then assign that 0 to the `ch` variable, and use the value of the assignment (which is 0) in the `if` statement. As 0 evaluates to `false`, the the second message is printed.